# Bind class method to AJAX success callback within event handler bound outside of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

### My issue:

I have created a JavaScript class that is used by our dev team across our site. It is essentially functionality for a grid/table like structure that allows the user to select items and perform actions on these items with provided action buttons.

**Action button workflow:**

- User clicks action button
- Popup appears: "Are you sure you want to perform this action on these items?"

  - *User clicks "Yes": AJAX call is made and popup closes upon AJAX success.*
  - *User clicks "No": Popup closes.*

Right now, these action buttons are individually bound in jQuery by our Devs on each page that needs it. Any given page could have a handful of event bindings.

After successful completion of any of these actions, I would like to run `Grid.afterActionComplete()` from any given instantiation. **I would like to run `Grid.afterActionComplete()` within the actions AJAX success callback.** I know I could expose (return) `afterActionComplete` in my class and have the Devs run the function themselves, but this is not ideal.

### My requirements:

- Would like to keep the amount of additional code for Devs to a minimum
- Many AJAX request can be made from any given page (some from non-action buttons), so using a global `ajaxSuccess` event wouldn't necessarily work. Plus, I would hate to use an event with that global of a scope.

### My question is two-fold:

1. How could I dynamically bind `Grid.afterActionComplete()` to any given action's AJAX success callback? (if possible)
2. How would I best incorporate the action bindings into the Grid class upon instantiation to further encapsulate my code?

### My sample code:

```
/* [START] Pre-existing code */
var Grid = function(gridID){
    var gridID = $(gridID),
        afterActionComplete = function(){
            // Ideally, I'd like to bind the function here
        },
        refresh = function(){
            // Refresh grid
        },

        return {
            refresh : refresh
        }
}

var popup = function(){
    $('.popup').show();
    // Pops up a window with an Action button and Cancel button
    // Just a placeholder to help explain concept
}
/* [END] Pre-existing code */



/* 
    [START] Dev defined code
        Devs will be creating these event bindings across the
        site. 
*/
var myGrid = new Grid("#grid1");

$('#actionPopupButton').click(function(){

    popup();

    $('.popup #actionButton').click(function(){

        $.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {

          myGrid.refresh();

          $('.popup').hide();

          // I'd like to inject Grid.afterActionComplete() here
          // Maybe create custom event and trigger() it here?
          // Ideally, I would love to not require the Devs insert additional code hre, but I'm not sure that's possible

        }); 

    });

});
/* [END] Dev defined code */
```

I've been pondering these questions for a week or so now, and would love any suggestions to help me solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong. You want `Grid.afterActionComplete()` called only on *specific* AJAX requests, correct? This is why you cannot use `.ajaxSuccess()`? If that is the case, the best thing you can do is to trigger a custom event.

If you feel that is too much work for the developers, you can abstract the `$.post` functionality inside a custom function of your `Grid` class. After you execute the callback, you can then make the call to `Grid.afterActionComplete()`. If it is mandatory that `Grid.afterActionComplete()` be called after those requests, it would make more sense to take this route since it seems to be part of the contract. This way you can protect the developers from themselves (i.e., if they forgot to call the function or trigger the custom event) by making it so that they can only make the post using the `Grid` API.

Comment: I did see `ajaxSuccess` when looking for solutions, but there can be many AJAX requests made from one given page, so just this alone wouldn't solve my issue.

Comment: No problem. It is a bit complex/specific. Yes, they would be calling it from the success handler anyway, but the scope for `ajaxSuccess` is too global for my project's sake. Maybe if there were some way to scope `ajaxSuccess` to only the action buttons would work.

Comment: @FillipPeyton I think I understand what you're going for now. Check out my edit.

Comment: Thanks @Vivin Paliath, that's more along the lines of what I'm looking for. I'm going to leave the question open in case there are any other solutions arise.

Comment: Sure. What you're trying to do is similar to Aspect-Oriented Programming. So you can read up on that for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the "developer code" is very similar, I would think ideally you would want to have the developers pass in appropriate parameters instead of create a bunch of very similar code.

For instance, if you made the `popup` method part of `Grid` and has the `url` and callback passed to the function you could do something like this:

```
popup = function(url, callback){
    var that = this;

    $('.popup').show();

    $('.popup #actionButton').click(function(){

        $.post( url, function( data ) {

            // call the passed in callback
            callback(data);

            // do your post-callback stuff
            that.refresh();      // assuming this happens in every callback

            $('.popup').hide();  // assuming this happens in every callback

            that.afterActionComplete();
        });
    });
}
```

Then your example developer code would become this:

```
var myGrid = new Grid("#grid1");

$('#actionPopupButton').click(function(){

    myGrid.popup("ajax/test.html", function(data){
        // do instance-specific stuff here
    });

});
```

Comment: I definitely agree with your first statement. I was thinking of having another parameter passed to the `Grid` constructor that is an object/array of functions/bindings and work `afterActionComplete` in there somehow. Though, that idea never fully took working form...

Comment: As I'm thinking about this more, I think I will end up using your strategy, but in a slightly different way. Rather than a `popup` method in `Grid`, I think I'll create an `action` method. I'll then have Devs pass through binding data and reconstruct it in the method. Thanks for your help!